# How to create executable jar with maven and system dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, build, executable-jar

I have few system dependencies in my maven project which I have included like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>Com.myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}\lib\myArtifact-1.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to create a executable jar [fat jar] which includes all the required dependencies , so the jar can run standalone .

I am using "maven-assembly-plugin" for packaging in this way:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin<artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true<addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.Application</mainClass>
            </manifest>
         </archive>
         <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
         </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that when the package is created the system dependencies are not included in the jar and I encounter ClassNotFound exceptions while I run it.

Can someone guide me with the correct way of configurations?

Update:

As few people mentioned I could install of the dependencies to local repository . The problem here is that We have a automated build server which gets triggered when ever we commit to the repo. I really don't want to install them on the remote build server.

Comment: Why not install the system dependencies first into the local repository?

Comment: To elaborate on @JFabianMeier, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602256/7228218).

Comment: Where is the system scope dependency coming from? This will no being packaged by default with maven-assembly-plugin (need supplemental configuration)...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the response. These dependency are coming from the project directory , i.e file system.

Answer (score 0):

Digging deep , found this hacky configuration (NOT recommended!!)

Reference this xml in the maven assembly plugin:

```
<configuration>   
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>   
    <descriptors>     
        <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>   
    </descriptors> 
</configuration>
```

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>jar-with-all-dependencies</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

 </assembly>
```